# Rewrite dynamic URL to another dynamic URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic

I need to Rewrite 
http://www.domain.net/img.php?id=example.jpg to 
http://www.domain.net/index.php?id=example.jpg

example.jpg is changing.
I am not common with htaccess syntax. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^img\.php$ /index.php [L,NC]
```

QUERY_STRING will automatically be carried over to `/index.php`

Comment: Just to clarify, the section at the end of the RewriteRule, `[L,NC,QSA]` are flags. The `L` means stop processing any additional rules, the `NC` means process this case-insensitively, and the `QSA` means leave the query string intact.

Comment: QSA means query string append (actually that wasn't needed in this rule) Let me edit.

Comment: QSA is needed only when one is modifying query parameters.